# In `method_missing': unknown property or method: `document' (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, watir

Could someone explain what the following error means?

```
E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/ie-class.rb:488:in `method_missing': unknown property or method: `document' (NoMethodError)
HRESULT error code:0x80010108
  The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.
from E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/ie-class.rb:488:in `document'
from E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/page-container.rb:31:in `page'
from E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/page-container.rb:55:in `html'
from E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/xpath_locator.rb:7:in `xmlparser_document_object'
from E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/xpath_locator.rb:30:in `elements_by_xpath'
from E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/locator.rb:111:in `locate_elements_by_xpath_css_ole'
from E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/locator.rb:209:in `locate'
from E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/input_elements.rb:5:in `locate'
from E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/element.rb:63:in `assert_exists'
from E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/element.rb:414:in `perform_action'
from E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/element.rb:269:in `click!'
from E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/element.rb:211:in `click'
```

I use some code in which I need to make the following checks  - if needed title is found - attach those to the window, if not - attach window by its url.

```
class Title
  def initialize(title)
    @@a = title
    $ie=Watir::IE.attach(:title, @@a) 
    rescue Watir::Exception::NoMatchingWindowFoundException
    puts ("could not find browser")
    r.addtoReport(testReport, "check page element", "FAILED", "Page title not found")
  end
end


if Title.new("Company")
else 
  $ie=Watir::IE.attach(:title,"http://")
end
```

Another variant is:

```
class Title
  def initialize(title,title1)
    @@a = title
    @@b=title1
    $ie=Watir::IE.attach(:title, @@a)  
    rescue Watir::Exception::NoMatchingWindowFoundException
    puts ("could not find browser")
    r.addtoReport(testReport, "check page element", "FAILED", "Page title not found")
    else
    $ie=Watir::IE.attach(:url, @@b)  
  end
end

Title.new("Company","http://")
```

Before attaching window:

```
$ie.button(:xpath, "//input[contains(@onclick, \"path\")]").click
```

Comment: Have you maybe closed IE before watir had finished with it?

Comment: It looks like the error message occurred while clicking an element. Is there another part of the script?

Comment: looks like it because of using $ie, but if i use ie2, ie3  - undefined local variable or method `ie2' for main:Object (NameError)

Comment: I could open 2 popup window using this script, on the third error occurs..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for reviving an old post but this info must be somewhere.
RE: It means watir is not founding the URL content.
If you are pointing to localhost try running tests as administrator.

Comment: You've posted this as an answer.

Comment: I know. Was it wrong?
I did it because everytime I looked up for help when I had this error, this is one of the first results the search engine shows. So I posted this answer here because I solved this error running tests as administrator.
But I know this question was asked 10 months ago so I was a little worry about posting in such an old question.